# Reporting Services - show multiple values for a column horizontally rather than vertically

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a report where row data can have the same data, apart from the data in the last column. Just adding the data to a table results in this:

| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | Column 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc | 1111 | 234345 |
| 1 | def | 2222 | 435656 |
| 1 | def | 2222 | 423233 |
| 1 | xyz | 1234 | 145423 |

I want to show the data like this, where if a row has multiple values for Column 4 value, additional Column 4's are added horizontally:

| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | Column 4 | Column 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc | 1111 | 234345 |  |
| 1 | def | 2222 | 435656 | 423233 |
| 1 | xyz | 1234 | 145423 |  |

I've tried adding a Parent Group to Column 4, which is close to what I want, but every row is given it's own column for the Column 4 value so it ends up like this:

| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | Column 4 | Column 4 | Column 4 | Column 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc | 1111 | 234345 |  |  |  |
| 1 | def | 2222 |  | 435656 | 423233 |  |
| 1 | xyz | 1234 |  |  |  | 145423 |

etc...

Is there a way to achieve the layout I require?

Comment: can you show your raw data and your design view of the report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a small change to your dataset query.

Here I have recreated your sample data table as a table variable called `@t' . Then I query the table and add a column which gives us a unique index for each 'Column4' value within each Column1-3 group

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (Column1 int,  Column2 varchar(10), Column3 int, Column4 int)
INSERT INTO @t VALUES
(1, 'abc', 1111, 234345) ,
(1, 'def', 2222, 435656) ,
(1, 'def', 2222, 423233) ,
(1, 'xyz', 1234, 145423) 

SELECT 
          *
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Column1, Column2, Column3 ORDER BY Column4) as Col4Index
    FROM @t
```

Now in your report, add a matrix with one rowgroup. This will group on `Column1`, `Column2` and `Column3`

Now add a column group that is grouped on `Col4Index`

Add your first 3  columns to the matrix making sure they are all in the single rowgroup (just add additional columns inside the group first and then select the correct field for each.

Drop the `Column4` field into the [Data] placeholder and finally set the header for this column to an expression (optional) like this

```
="Column4_" & Fields!Col4Index.Value
```

The report design looks like this

[image]

The final output looks like this

[image]