# SSRS column grouping creating empty cells

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I am not able to build an SSRS report from a simple SQL query ( SELECT *
FROM TblTeaching). I want to display as below

| Day | Period | Teachers |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Monday | P1 | AL |  |
|  | P2 | AZT | MJ |
|  | P3 | MJ |  |

But it currently looks like below

| Day | Period | Teachers |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Monday | P1 | AL |  |  |
|  | P2 |  | AZT |  |
|  |  |  |  | MJ |
|  | P3 |  |  | MJ |

Raw data:

| Class | Day | Period | Teacher |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | Friday | P1 | AZT |
| 6 | Friday | P2 | MJ |
| 6 | Monday | P2 | AL |
| 6 | Monday | P3 | MJ |
| 6 | Thursday | P4 | MJ |
| 6 | Thursday | P3 | AZT |
| 6 | Tuesday | P1 | AZT |
| 6 | Tuesday | P3 | AZT |
| 6 | Wednesday | P4 | AZT |
| 6 | Wednesday | P5 | USC |
| 6 | Tuesday | P1 | KSH |
| 6 | Tuesday | P1 | MJ |
| 6 | Wednesday | P1 | KFM |

Comment: please show your raw data (exactly as it comes from the dataset query) and your report design

Comment: Class       Day     Period  Teacher
6       Friday P1 AZT
6      Friday         P2 MJ
6     Monday P2 AL
6     Monday P3 MJ
6     Thursday P4 MJ
6    Thursday P3 AZT
6    Tuesday P1 AZT
6    Tuesday P3 AZT
6    Wednesday P4 AZT
6    Wednesday P5 USC
6    Tuesday P1 KSH
6    Tuesday P1 MJ
6    Wednesday P1 KFM

Comment: @AlanSchofield Sorry didnt know how to send raw data and I dont have a report design at the moment its in tabular form.

Comment: Please edit your question and show the data. It's difficult to read when it's just in a a comment. I've done this for you now.

Comment: Please see this answer I posted very recently, it should give you enough info to get the report you want https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72203191/reporting-services-show-multiple-values-for-a-column-horizontally-rather-than/72231215#72231215